# Infinite Loops in C++

Tags: c++, loops

I keep on receiving infinite loop errors when I try and run this program. Can anyone help me out and tell me why? Any assistance would be most appreciated. Thanks!

```
    void Increment(int);
    int main()
    {
      int count = 1;
      while(count < 10)
      cout << "the number after " << count; //Increment function
      Increment(count); //count+1
      cout << " is " << count << endl;
      return 0;
    }
    void Increment (int nextNumber)
    {
      nextNumber++; //parameter +1
    }
```

Comment: You're changing it locally - Pass by reference!

Comment: Why didn't you do nextNumber++ directly instead of making it a function?

Comment: It's his while statement as well. It has no brackets around it.

Comment: And you don't have braces on your while.  You're printing the `cout` continually.  And the increment isn't by reference.

Comment: If only all questions were so easy.

Comment: I remember an exact duplicate of this months ago. It had the same two problems in the code also.

Comment: @crush Yes, because what SO really needs is 9 answers to every question, half of which only fix half the problem. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The braces are required if your `while` loop uses more than one line. Actually, you should always use braces just to avoid confusion. Moreover, your `Increment` function should take its parameter by-reference, so it won't operate on a copy (another cause for an infinite loop):

```
void Increment(int&);

int main()
{
    int count = 1;

    while (count < 10)
    {
        std::cout << "the number after " << count;
        Increment(count);
        std::cout << " is " << count << std::endl;
    }
}

void Increment(int& nextNumber)
{
    nextNumber++;
}
```

Comment: @The10thDoctor What do you mean? Your question has nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: I was referring to the "almost" question by @ViniyoShouta.

Answer (score 8):

You're passing by value instead of by reference:

Do this instead:

```
void Increment (int& nextNumber)
{
  nextNumber++; //parameter +1
}
```

Additionally, you are missing the closing braces for your while loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
while(count < 10)
    cout << "the number after " << count; //Increment function
```

This is an infinite loop, as count is *always* the same value, and not changed by this loop.

This is why you **must** have brackets (`{}`) around loops, otherwise you make mistakes like this.

To re-write your code, and illustrate what is happening:

```
void Increment(int);
int main()
{
  int count = 1;
  while(count < 10) 
  {
      cout << "the number after " << count; //Increment function
  }
  Increment(count); //count+1
  cout << " is " << count << endl;
  return 0;
}


void Increment (int nextNumber)
{
  nextNumber++; //parameter +1
}
```

Comment: Also, the parameter should be passed by reference.

Comment: Yeah, without fixing the function, wrapping his code in `{}` isn't going to help anything.

Comment: And fixing the function won't fix anything if he doesn't have braces.  Chicken-and-egg problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major issues, you are missing braces for the `while` loop, should be as follows:

```
while(count < 10)
{
    cout << "the number after " << count; //Increment function
    Increment(count); //count+1
    cout << " is " << count << endl;
}
```

The second issue is that, you are passing `count` to `Increment` by value, if you want to update `count` you can pass by reference:

```
 void Increment (int &nextNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `count` by value due to which it is not incremented. Pass by value means that a local copy of a variable is used in the function and it does not affect original variable. You need to pass the address using `& operator`. You can use this:-

```
void Increment (int& nextNumber)
{
  nextNumber++; 
}
```

You have also not enclosed **while loop** with braces `{   }` which can have an undesired effect on the execution of the program.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Increment` function does nothing, because it accepts the parameter `nextNumber` *by value*. This means that it operates on a copy of the variable passed into it, so its changes are lost when the function exits. Instead, make it accept a variable *by reference*:

```
void Increment (int &nextNumber)
    {
      nextNumber++; //parameter +1
    }
```

You must also surround the code within the `while` loop with `{}`:

```
  while(count < 10)
  {
    cout << "the number after " << count; //Increment function
    Increment(count); //count+1
    cout << " is " << count << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  while(count < 10)
  cout << "the number after " << count; //Increment function
```

You need brackets otherwise the while will only execute the cout over and over again without executing the increment function

Comment: That's not the only problem.

Comment: That's part of the problem. Fixing the pass-by-reference problem in Increment without making this change will not fix the overall program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are passing by value.When you pass the number to Increment it makes a copy called nextNumber and increments it.This change is not reflected in the sent argument.Thus count was never increased.

To rectify , you can either return a value from increment or call be reference.

**Call by value**

```
int Increment (int nextNumber)
{
  return nextNumber+1; //parameter +1
}
```

The call statement here is:

```
count=Increment(count);
```

**Call by reference:**

I am assuming you don't know what this means, basically you will pass in the address of the variable so you don't make a copy in the increment but rather work on the orginal variable itself.

```
void Increment (int& nextNumber)
{
  nextNumber++; //parameter +1
}
```

The call statement here:

```
 Increment(count);
```

Please ask if you have more questions.